# For Loop that adds a TEXTAFTER Formula to Range

Tags: excel, vba, string, for-loop, count

I am trying to write a `For` loop in VBA that adds a `TEXTAFTER` formula to a range of cells based on the values in the adjacent column. There's an `IF/ELSE` statement within the `For` loop that changes the formula based on the number of a specific character. The count of the "-" character is based collected from a function that counts the number of occurrences of that character. See the second block of code for that function. The function I created to count the number of occurrences for the dash character in the string is not picking up the number of characters that it is supposed to. I don't know what is missing in the function that is preventing the `IF` statement from returning the correct count for the dashes.

This is the code for the loop that I have tired

1. `For` Loop that iterates through range of cells.

   ```vb
   row = 0

   For row = 1 To rngThird.Rows.Count
       Set rngStart = wsTest.Range("A1")

       If CNT_SYMBOLS(rngStart.Offset(row, 0).Value, "-") >= 2 Then
           strTAFormula = "=TRIM(TEXTAFTER(" & rngStart.Offset(row, 1).Address & "," & """" & "-" & """" & ",2,1,1," & rngStart.Offset(row, 1).Address & "))"

           rngStart.Offset(row, 0).Select
           Selection.Formula = strTAFormula
       Else
           strTAFormula = "=TRIM(TEXTAFTER(" & rngStart.Offset(row, 1).Address & "," & """" & "-" & """" & ",1,1,1," & rngStart.Offset(row, 1).Address & "))"

           rngStart.Offset(row, 0).Select
           Selection.Formula = strTAFormula
       End If
   Next
   ```
2. Function that counts symbols in cells with text.

   ```vb
   Function CNT_SYMBOLS(str As String, character As String) As Integer
       cntcharacter = UBound(Split(str, character))
   End Function
   ```

Comment: Can you post a list of possible strings that your `CNT_SYMBOLS` function would parse and what your expected value should be?

Comment: "adds a TEXTAFTER formula to a range of cells based on the values in the adjacent column" but the choice of formula is based on the value of same cell it gets added to, not an adjacent column?   `CNT_SYMBOLS(rngStart.Offset(row, 0).Value, "-")` and (effectively, if you skip the Select step) `rngStart.Offset(row, 0).Formula = strTAFormula`

Comment: Here's a generic example of what I need it to do.

Original String: "Specialty Product Gel - 12300678CA" 
TEXTAFTER Formula Result: "12300678CA"

Sometimes there are more than one dashes in a product name because the product name is hyphenated.
Ex. "Specialty Hyphenated-Product - 12365400CE"
I need it to switch to the TEXTAFTER statement that returns just the product number by looking for the second dash.

Comment: If you pass a negative number as an argument to the `instance_num` parameter, TEXTAFTER will start searching *from the end of the text*, so if you pass -1 it will always return the product number (assuming it comes after the last dash in the input text)

Answer (score 0):

To return the last part of a "-" delimited string you can pass in -1 (negative number means search from the end of the string backwards)

Eg:

```
=TRIM(TEXTAFTER(A2,"-",-1))
```

That will always return the product number if it's the last part of the input.

So you only need to do something like this:

```
With wsTest.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    .Formula = "=TRIM(TEXTAFTER(" & _
                .Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False) & _
                 ", ""-"", -1))"
End With
```